# Change sources encoding to inherited in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding

I have lots of problems with encoding and Eclipse.
I configured my Eclipse to "UTF-8" by default but sometimes, I have some projects whiches are in CP1252. So for dealing with that, I configue theses projects with "CP1252" :
[image]

I see all children folders are with this encoding because they are configured with "Inherited from container (CP1252)" but I don't know why my java sources hasn't this option :
[image]

And I cannot remove *.java files from contents types because all "Remove" buttons are greyed :
[image]

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks !

Comment: You should be able to remove the 'Default encoding' value from the content type (just delete the text). I think that will switch it to inherit from the container.

Comment: @greg-449 Hello, thanks you for your reply. That's actually works if I delete the text then click "Update" and then "Apply and Close". You can write it as answer. Thanks you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the 'Default encoding' string so that it is empty should get the setting inherited from the container.

You need to press the 'Update' button after changing the string to update the default setting and then close the preference page with 'Apply and Close'.

Note: Content types like "Java Source File" cannot be removed because they are contributed by Eclipse plug-ins. Only content types you add manually can be removed.